# Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Ingress unhealthy backend

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have the following deployment running in Google Cloud Platform (GCP):

```
    kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: mybackend
  labels:
    app: backendweb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backendweb
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backendweb
        tier: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mybackend
          image: eu.gcr.io/teststuff/backend:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
```

This uses the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mybackend
  labels:
    app: backendweb
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: backendweb
    tier: web
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
```

Which uses this ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: backend-ip
  labels:
    app: backendweb
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: mybackend
    servicePort: 8081
```

When I spin all this up in Google Cloud Platform however, I get the following error message on my ingress:

```
All backend services are in UNHEALTHY state
```

I've looked through my pod logs with no indication about the problem.  Grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this problem is caused by not returning 200 on route `'/'` for your pod. Please check your pod configurations. If you don't want to return 200 at route `'/'`, you could add a readiness rule for health check like this:

```
readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 80
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: For my service, which serves everything under a custom path (`/v1`), the only thing that worked was to add an HTTP handler at `/` as you said. Adding custom readiness/liveness probes didn't help. The service was shown as ready by K8s/K9s, worked OK through port-forwarding. But I just couldn't get it to work through the public IP, unless I added a dumb 200 return on the default path `/`. Thanks for pointing that out, after a day of frustration, at least I can use this hack.